# Definition of Copy Number Abundance

Tags: copy-number

Reading from [this paper](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2024534):

> The remaining 9 new copy-number alterations showed altered coverage patterns on whole-genome sequencing but could not be confirmed by orthogonal methods because of their small size, **low abundance**, or both (Fig. 2C, Fig. S2C, and Table S5)

In the supplementary file, CNA abundance as percentage is defined as:

$$Abundance = \frac{2^{L2R} - 1}{\frac{CN}{2} - 1}*100$$

where L2R is the log$_{2}$ normalized coverage ratio vs. a panel of normals and CN is the estimated copy number for the event.

I haven't found a better definition/explanation behind "CNA abundance", is it defined elsewhere, or is it a common term in CNA analysis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess by analyzing the definition is that CNA abundance is a proxy for the percentage of (tumor) cells carrying the alteration.